# vue ref($refs) undefined in mounted nextTick

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Because of vue ref undefined, I am suffering from a headache.
The component structure is described below.

If you have a Parent component,
I have a Modal component as a child.
Modal has an unnamed slot tag.

Here is a partial code snippet:
We are changing the content to be displayed on the slot with v-if.

```
<modal v-if="visibleModal" :useBody="false" :useFull="true" @close="visibleModal = false">
  <template v-if="visibleModalContentsFlag == 'first'">
    <first @close="closeModal"
           @visibleBasicInfoModal="visibleModalContentsFlag = 'basic1'"
           @visiblePickupPlaceModal="visiblePickupPlace"
           @updateBasicInfo="updateBasicInfo($event)"
           @updatePickupPlace="updatePickupPlace($event)"
           @setReq="spotReq = $event"
           @inputConfirm="visibleModalContentsFlag = 'confirm'"
    />
  </template>
  <template v-if="visibleModalContentsFlag == 'basic1'">
    <input-basic :basicInfoModel="basicInfo"
                 @back="visibleModalContentsFlag='first'"
                 @next="visibleModalContentsFlag='basic2'"/>
  </template>

  <template v-if="visibleModalContentsFlag == 'basic2'">
    <input-step-1 :basicInfoModel="basicInfo"
                  :basicInfoFocusInput="focusInput"
                  @back="visibleModalContentsFlag='basic1'"
                  @submitComplete="stepOneComplete"/>
  </template>

  <template v-if="visibleModalContentsFlag == 'pickup1'">
    <input-step-2 :pickupInfoModel="pickupInfo"
                  :pickupPlaceFocusInput="focusInput"
                  @back="visibleModalContentsFlag='first'"
                  @submitComplete="stepTwoComplete"
                  ref="inputStep2"/>
  </template>

  <template v-if="visibleModalContentsFlag == 'confirm'">
    <input-confirm :spotReq="spotReq"
                   @modifyBasicInfo="modifyBasicInfo($event)"
                   @modifyPickupPlaceInfo="modifyPickupPlaceInfo($event)"
                   @submitComplete="visibleModalContentsFlag = 'done'"/>
  </template>

  <template v-if="visibleModalContentsFlag == 'done'">
      <input-complete/>
  </template>

</modal>
```

---

```
<label class="row--v-center radios-block__item">
          <span class="col">
            <em>공용 냉장고</em>
          </span>
          <form-radio value="공용 냉장고" v-model="pickupInfoModel.pickup" ref="f_pickup1"/>
        </label>
        <label class="row--v-center radios-block__item">
          <span class="col">
            <em>문서 수발실</em>
          </span>
          <form-radio value="문서 수발실" v-model="pickupInfoModel.pickup" ref="f_pickup2"/>
        </label>
```

If you look at the input-step-2 component here, you can see that the above code is part of the input tag, but ref is specified in the input tag.

I want to give focus () to this ref tag.

```
this.$nextTick(()=>{
      console.log('fuck')
      console.log(this.$refs.inputStep2.$refs)
      console.log(this.$refs.inputStep2.$refs.f_pickup_detail)
    })
```

I tried to process as below, but I can not proceed due to undefined. sure,
The input-step-2 component will be undefined even if you try to mount it. So I solved the following problem as a temporary solution, but I do not like it. Is there any way I can solve it?

```
mounted(){
  if(!!this.pickupPlaceFocusInput){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.$refs[this.pickupPlaceFocusInput].$el.focus()
    },350)
  }
},
```

Comment: did you try to use custom directives in the input-step-2 component? also would be helpful if you can give this in a fiddle or some other online code editor